# Moment.js, FullCalendar.js datetime comparisons with timezone offsets

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm confused.

I have a textbox that is populated with a date and time (string) such as '09/07/2021 10:30'.

I convert this string to a moment like so:

```
var suggestedDateObj = moment(suggestedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

I then want to check if this date and time is in between time slots in a fullcalendar.js event object.  I do this like so:

```
var startDateObj = moment(value.start);
var endDateObj = moment(value.end);
if (suggestedDateObj.isBetween(startDateObj, endDateObj)) {}
```

However...it isn't working.  And it's due to timezone offset (i think).

suggestedDateObj returns a value with a UTC offset of +0100 (British Summer Time)

However my calendar event objects return a date with a UTC offset of +0000.  So when i check if '09/07/2021 10:30 **+0100**' is in between '09/07/2021 10:30 **+0000**' and '09/07/2021 11:30 **+0000**' it doesn't work!

I guess my question is really either:

- How can I create my suggestedDateObj moment with a timezone offset of zero? OR
- How can i tell fullcallendar events that the time it is displaying is actually BST (+0100)?  At the moment I don't specify the 'Timezone' parameter.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Hmm....this might work....although it feels a bit clunky:

```
 var tmoment1 = moment(suggestedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');    
            //create default date with specific timezone offset of zero
            var suggestedDateObj = moment().utcOffset(0);
            //set the date and time
            suggestedDateObj.set({
                day: tmoment1.day(),
                month: tmoment1.month(),
                year: tmoment1.year(),
                hour: tmoment1.hour(),
                minute: tmoment1.minute(),
                second: 0
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate `suggestedDateObj` in utc like that:

```
var suggestedDateObj = moment.utc(suggestedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');`
```

For the `.isBetween()` I suggest you to use the square bracket like forth parameter, like [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) says.

```
if (suggestedDateObj.isBetween(startDateObj, endDateObj, undefined, '[]'))
```

The square brackets indicate that the check must include the dates of the limiter

Comment: If the project is new remember that moment developpers recommend to use another library like Day.js (this one is very similar to moment). I leave you the documentation where they wrote that https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/